# What's the most idiomatic way in Java to dynamically call a function by name?

Tags: java, dry

I have a certain set of operations that I would like to be able to access dynamically by name.

If I were using JavaScript, I would represent them in a dictionary with the names of the operations as keys and the operation functions as values.

Then, for example, I could ask the user for the name of an operation, display the result of the operation if it exists, and display an error message if it doesn't exist, like so:

```js
var operations = {
  addition: function(a, b) { return a + b; },
  subtraction: function(a, b) { return a - b; },
  multiplication: function(a, b) { return a * b; }
  // etc.
};

var a = 4, b = 7;
var opName = prompt("Enter operation name:");
if (opName in operations) {
  alert("Result: " + operations[opName](a, b));
} else {
  alert("The operation '" + opName + "' does not exist.");
}
```

How would I do the same thing in Java? I could have a `Set<String>` of operation names and a function that uses a switch with a case for each operation, but that requires me to repeat each operation name twice, which makes the code more brittle and more tedious to write and maintain.

Is there a reasonably concise DRY pattern for this sort of thing in Java?

Comment: Have you considered using Java 8 lambdas?

Comment: @anubhavashok I'm writing code that I want to be able to integrate into an Android app, and Java 8 is not widely supported on Android devices.

Comment: Well, although not an elegant solution, one way to avoid the extra switch case statement would be to store functors in a map and run them identically.

Comment: *Why* are you wanting to do this? Generally speaking, the preferred Java approach would be to implement an interface and use a `Map<String,Foo>`.

Comment: There are 3 basic approaches. 1) Use a map 2) switch on the operation name 3) use an enum with an abstract method overridden by each constant.

Comment: @chrylis My actual use case is parsing a domain-specific markup language, but explaining all the details of that in the question is unnecessary, so I made a simpler example. Why does it seem so strange to you that anybody would want to do such a thing?

Comment: @PeterOlson It's not strange at all. In fact this is almost exactly the same as an example in Effective Java. In that book, an enum is used,

Comment: It's not strange that someone wants to do this. The specifics of the application suggest different approaches, however: Service Provider Interface, reflection, Groovy.

Comment: @PeterOlson It seems strange because it's not idiomatic in Java to do something like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a lot neater in Java 8 using lambdas:

```
Map<String, BinaryOperator<Integer>> operators = new TreeMap<>();
operators.put("add", (n1, n2) -> n1 + n2);
operators.put("minus", (n1, n2) -> n1 - n2);

if (operators.containsKey(opName)) {
    return operators.get(opName).apply(n1, n2);
}
```

But I gather from your comments that that is not an option. An alternative is to use an enum to contain your operations so that you can add new operations in one place:

```
enum Operation {
    PLUS {
        public int operate(int arg1, int arg2) {
            return arg1 + arg2;
        }
    },
    MINUS {
        public int operate(int arg1, int arg2) {
            return arg1 - arg2;
        }
    },
    ...

    abstract public int operate(int arg1, int arg2);
}

for (operation: Operations.values()) {
    if (operation.name().equals(opName))
        System.out.println("result = " + operation.operate(arg1, arg2));
        return;
    }
}
System.out.println("The Operation " + opName + " does not exist");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public interface Function {
    double run(double a, double b);
}

public class addFunction implements Function {
    double run(double a, double b) {
        return a+b;
    }
}
//...
Map<String, Function> operations = new HashMap<string, Function>();
operations.put("add", new addFunction());
//...
String op;
double a, b;
operations.get(op).run(a, b);
```

Comment: This still requires having to manage adding/removing operations in two places. If I want to add a new operation, I have to create a new class and also do an `operations.put`.

Comment: @PeterOlson You could use anonymous classes to get around that: `operations.put("add", new Function() { @Override public double run(double a, double b) { return a + b; }});`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same thing in Java without using Java8:

```
public interface Operation<T,R> {
    R perform(T... args);
}

public void test() {
    Map<String, Operation> operations = new HashMap<String, Operation>() {
        {
            this.put("addition", new Operation<Integer, Integer>() {
                public Integer perform(Integer... args) {
                    return args[0] + args[1];
                }});
        }
    };

    String operation = "";
    Integer a = 1;
    Integer b = 1;
    if (operations.containsKey(operation)) {
        System.out.println("Result: " + operations.get(operation).perform(a, b));
    } else {
        System.out.println("The operation '" + operation + "' does not exist.");
    }
}
```

You can move that anonymous class into a separate file if you prefer that, too.

If you need arguments of different types you will have to either juggle with generics or change the argument type to `Object` and then do casts. Not pretty but that's the price of static typing.

Also the compiler will throw you a warning (using raw `Operation`) but not much to do here if you want to store operations of different types in the same map. A way out would be to make several maps for different types.

Comment: As always I don't mind down votes but I would appreciate a comment or two.

Comment: You have an upvote from me, it does what I want, even though *oh my goodness Java is so verbose!*

Comment: @PeterOlson verbose and still you will be getting compiler warnings as I mentioned :-) It's much better in Java8 and Scala though. Also personally I like the verbosity while working with big projects but that's just me.